# How to use flashpaper in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, flash, file

i want to display swf document via Adobe Flash Paper software  in our asp.net web page.
  can any one describe how i embed flash paper API in .net?

Answer (score 0):

The FlashPaper software produces an .swf file for your document. In order to embed such a document in your web page you need to embed the .swf file via FlashPlayer in your page.

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
            codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" 
            WIDTH="550" HEIGHT="400" id="myDocument">
      <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="myFlashPaperFile.swf">
      <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
      <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#FFFFFF>
  <EMBED href="myFlashPaperFile.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#FFFFFF
      WIDTH="550" HEIGHT="400" NAME="myDocument" ALIGN="" 
      TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash"
      PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
  </EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

Where the example says *myFlashPaperFile.swf*, you'll need to put the URL where the swf containing your document can be retreived by the player. You also may want to adjust the width, height and bgcolor attributes and parameters. You'll need both the object and embed tags in order to support all browsers.

A good alternative for embedding Flash in web pages is to use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) rather than to create the object/embed tags manually.